# Displaying json data in a clear format

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

How can a value from json data and print out in a html text field.
 json data are looking like this: `{"name":"paul"}` but i want to display only paul in my text field. my codeigniter php code are below:

```
$data['name']= $this->name_model->get_names($obj);

            $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
           $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
           $string = $this->output->get_output();
           echo $string;
```

jquery,ajax codes are below:

```
if(obj != ''){
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url();?>Geting_names/name_listing",
            method:"POST",
            dataType: "text",
            data: {obj},
            success:function(resp){

            $("div#sending_field").html('<div class="alert alert-success">' + resp +'</div>');
```

Comment: in response just send the html code. do not send json

Comment: Dont use eval,parsing json can be done natively in Javascript. No need for eval.You can use JSON.parse and it will return you an object parsed by the string containing the json text.

Comment: after that how shall i print the value "paul" only Sir?

Comment: You Can Use Object.keys to map the values, and Object.values to get the values for ex - var obj = JSON.parse(resp);
var values = Object.values(obj);
console.log(values);

Comment: it works! than you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In Javascript success method

```
var obj1 = JSON.parse(resp);

$("div#sending_field").html('<div class="alert alert-success">' + obj1.name +'</div>');
```

Comment: the result become " undefined"